# How do I make base URL common for all my Rest API's

Tags: rest, api

I'm new to REST API development,

I have 3 small java projects each having some API's in them.

Sample URLs:

```
https://example.com/project1/rest/class1/api_name1
https://example.com/project1/rest/class2/api_name2

https://example.com/project2/rest/class3/api_name3
https://example.com/project2/rest/class4/api_name4

https://example.com/project3/rest/class5/api_name5
https://example.com/project3/rest/class5/api_name6
```

Each url is different, I want base url common for each API
something like this

```
https://example.com/something_common/api_name1
https://example.com/something_common/api_name2
https://example.com/something_common/api_name3
https://example.com/something_common/api_name4
https://example.com/something_common/api_name5
https://example.com/something_common/api_name6
```

my question is, Is it at all possible and if yes then how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it:

- If you use Apache, check [How To Use Apache HTTP Server As Reverse-Proxy Using mod_proxy Extension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension). In your case, it would look like:

  `ProxyPass /something_common/api_name1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/project1/rest/class1/api_name1`
- Or Nginx - check [Understanding Nginx HTTP Proxying, Load Balancing, Buffering, and Caching](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching) or [Virtual Hosts on nginx (CSC309)](https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0):

  ```
  location /something_common/api_name1 {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/project1/rest/class1/api_name1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
  }
  ```